# PHP Using dropdown to filter mysql table, without js or form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a value from a dropdown to limit a mysql table selection, without JS, directly from a page (so, NOT from a form, but using an action tag). Problem is, dropdown works, redisplay works, but I can't get the selected value into $_GET(sel_type). Can anybody help?

```
echo " <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?sel_type=$sel_type'><b>
    <select name='s_type' type='text' title='Alleen het geselecteerde item-type zien?' value='".$sel_type."'> ";
        while($fetch_type = mysql_fetch_array($droptype)) {
            echo "  <option id ='" . $fetch_type['type_id']."' value='" . $fetch_type['type_id']."' ";
            if ($sel_type==$fetch_type['type_oms']) echo "selected='selected'";
            echo ">" . $fetch_type['type_oms']."</option>";
             };
echo "  </select></a></b></td>";
```

Comment: `<select>` tags require a form submission OR an asynchronous request to be made to the server. Otherwise, you won't be able to get the selected value to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Without `JS` you need a `form` to submit the value of the `select`:

```
if( isset( $_GET['s_type'] ) ){
    //do something with the select here
    $sel_type   = $_GET['s_type'];
}

echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='GET' id='frm' name='frm'>";
echo " <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><b>
    <select name='s_type' title='Alleen het geselecteerde item-type zien?' onchange='document.frm.submit()'> ";
        while($fetch_type = mysql_fetch_array($droptype)) {
            echo "  <option id ='" . $fetch_type['type_id']."' value='" . $fetch_type['type_id']."' ";
            if ($sel_type==$fetch_type['type_oms']) echo "selected='selected'";
            echo ">" . $fetch_type['type_oms']."</option>";
             };
echo "  </select></a></b></td>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Actually, it's in double quotes... the single quotes are for the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I see, but $sel_type is still empty. eg it does not inherit the value selected.

Comment: Yes, missed that. @JeffRupert. Changes the answer to post with a form

Comment: So, using a Form, the a tag becomes the submit?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm not clear enough, but I want the select-action to be the submit. I don't want another submit-button.

Comment: Then you would need `JS`, see `onchange='document.frm.submit()'` on the `select` @Theo

Comment: Sorry, Nil'z, it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least a `<form>` tag to get a `select` tag working without JS. And you can't use a `select` block element inside an inline `a` element. And a `select` field does not have an attribute `type` and a `value` attribute neither.

```
echo " <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <form method=\"GET\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\"><select name=\"sel_type\" title=\"Alleen het geselecteerde item-type zien?\"> ";
        while($fetch_type = mysql_fetch_array($droptype)) {
            echo "  <option id ='" . $fetch_type['type_id']."' value='" . $fetch_type['type_id']."' ";
            if ($sel_type==$fetch_type['type_oms']) echo "selected='selected'";
            echo ">" . $fetch_type['type_oms']."</option>";
             };
echo "  </select></form></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To anybody out there, who is interested in the "impossible": I've solved my own question, without the use of JS or Form/submit, so you can can use it anywhere, incl server-side. The answer is something I'm using everyday (in menu's) and I still could not make the connection, until today.
The solution includes some fancy CSS, which you can simplify, if you want the look-and-feel of a normal dropdown box.
Here is the php code, followed by the css:

```
    echo "<td><ul id='dropselect' class='droptable'>
    <li class='droptable'><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?sel_type=All types' title='Click one of the types in the list, to limit the db selection'><span>All types</span></a>
    <ul>";
while($fetch_type = mysql_fetch_array($droptype)) {
echo "<li><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?sel_type=".$fetch_type['type_desc']."'><span>".$fetch_type['type_desc']."</span></a>";
    };
echo "</li></ul></ul></td>";
```

Here is the CSS; you can copy it straight into your styleheet:

```
    ul#dropselect,ul#dropselect ul{
margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;background-color:#dedede;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#5f5f5f;
-moz-box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;}
    ul#dropselect ul{
display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:100%;
-moz-box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
background-color:#79beff;border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-color:#d4d4d4;padding:0 10px 10px;}
    ul#dropselect li:hover>*{
display:block;}
    ul#dropselect li{
position:relative;display:block;white-space:nowrap;font-size:0;float:left;}
    ul#dropselect li:hover{
z-index:1;}
    ul#dropselect ul ul{
position:absolute;left:100%;top:0;}
    ul#dropselect{
font-size:0;z-index:999;position:relative;display:inline-block;zoom:1;padding:0;
*display:inline;}
    * html ul#dropselect li a{
display:inline-block;}
    ul#dropselect>li{
margin:0;}
    ul#dropselect a:active, ul#dropselect a:focus{
outline-style:none;}
    ul#dropselect a{
display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;font:bold 15px Trebuchet MS;color:#55aaff;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;cursor:pointer;padding:10px;background-color:#c1c1c1;background-image:url("mainbk.png");background-repeat:repeat;background-position:0 0;border-width:0 0 0 1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#C0C0C0;}
    ul#dropselect ul li{
float:none;margin:10px 0 0;}
    ul#dropselect ul a{
text-align:left;padding:2px;background-color:#79beff;background-image:none;border-width:0;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;font:15px Tahoma;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;}
    ul#dropselect li:hover>a,ul#dropselect li a.pressed{
background-color:#79beff;border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style:solid;color:#ffffff;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;background-image:url("mainbk.png");background-position:0 100px;text-decoration:none;}
    ul#dropselect span{
display:block;overflow:visible;background-position:right center;background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-right:2px;}
    ul#dropselect ul li:hover>a,ul#dropselect ul li a.pressed{
background-color:#FFFFFF;background-image:none;color:#0978b3;text-decoration:none;}
```